# USB partition not showing up as drive

Tags: windows-10, usb, partitioning, device-manager

I recently formatted a 128gb Sandisk USB on my desktop (Window 10). The device was partitioned in two: one that was about 3gb (FAT), and the other 115gb (exFAT). The device worked all fine on my desktop, with both partitions being accessible and writable.

After a few days on a trip I plugged the USB into my laptop and I can only access the 3gb portion of the drive. I don't have my desktop around to confirm, but I don't doubt it will work on it.

Device manager shows the following:
[image]

which I've never seen before; usually if a partition or device is unaccessible one just sees unallocated. I've tried assigning the 115gb partition a drive letter but device manager keeps giving me an error saying device list is not up to date (despite me refreshing).

What is going on?

Comment: It appears like the partition table is corrupted.  TestDisk might be able to repair it.

Comment: I'll check it out! Not to worried about the data as I have backups, just a weird situation. Wish I could test it on my desktop

Comment: @Ramhound cool program! was able to get the data off.

Comment: Perfect candidate for a self-answer

Answer (score 1):

To be able to work with USB drives that have multiple partitions, your PC has to be at least Windows 10, v1703, with the most recent version of the Windows ADK installed.

Comment: If you can add a source, the answer would be perfect.

Comment: This seems true. Compare [this discussion](https://superuser.com/q/1268559/432690#comment1869333_1268559).